# Get error when using the K-means algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

#I Got **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'.** error in juypter notebook when using scikit-learn.#

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

class ClusterSimilarity(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__(self, n_clusters=10, gamma=1.0, random_state=None):
    self.n_clusters = n_clusters
    self.gamma = gamma
    self.random_state = random_state

def fit(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None):
    self.kmeans_ = KMeans(self.n_clusters, random_state=self.random_state)
    self.kmeans_.fit(X, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    return self  # always return self!

def transform(self, X):
    return rbf_kernel(X, self.kmeans_.cluster_centers_, gamma=self.gamma)

def get_feature_names_out(self, names=None):
    return [f"Cluster {i} similarity" for i in range(self.n_clusters)]


cluster_simil = ClusterSimilarity(n_clusters=10, gamma=1, random_state=42)
similarities = cluster_simil.fit_transform(housing_tr[["latitude", "longitude"]],
                                       sample_weight=housing_labels)
```

#The code works on google colab but get this error using jupyter notebook on my computer.#

Comment: make sure you are passing the data.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors